# Is HTTP request the only solution for an Android application to get informed of a change in a file placed in a PHP server?

Tags: php, android

An `Android` application as client needs to check the changes of a variable in a JSON file placed in a `PHP` server
With `HTTP` request from the application to the server, the variable could be retrieved (sent back to the application by `PHP` code utilizing `echo`)

The variable value shall be updated in the `Android` application as quick as possible
In other word, it's preferable if it gets updated in the `Android` application as soon as there is any changed in the server

It's possible to send HTTP request every interested seconds but it does not seem to be a true manner cause the variable may not change for several days while during all these several days, `HTTP` request is being sent and sent

Edit:
Is HTTP request the only solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to use **Push Notification ( FCM Technology )** in this case.
You can be notified whenever the variable has been changed and do whatever you want in the android application while the push notif been received.
Also there is no overload on server by calling a web-service to check the variable every minutes.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I accepted the answer, is there any other solution too

Comment: I've experienced this situation & push notif method seems to be a right way. You can also implement push notif by yourself through using socket programming & listener but needs much work to be done.